# Validate form input fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

1. I'm working on form validation. Everything is working fine what I actually want is I want to add some more input fields like checkbox, radio button, select and textarea, upload file and like so into the form I want them to be validated as well.
2. I got the email input error working but it is not working correctly as it should validate the email first and then it should remove the error message but it is removing the error message just after entering few characters.
3. I want the phone number to be validated. Like the user should enter 10 numeric digits that is in India if in another country that will differ I am a bit confused how to do it.
4. I want a success message to pop up when all the fields are correctly validated as they should. what I tried is this:

   ```
   $('.success_msg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
   $('input , textarea , select').val('').removeClass('valid');
   event.preventDefault();
   ```
5. I want all the fields to be cleared when all the validations are done and the success message is sent.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
var Validator = function(formObject) {
  this.form = $(formObject);

  var Elements = {
    name: {
      reg: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/,
      error: "Not a valid name.",
    },

    email: {
      reg: /^[a-z-0-9_+.-]+\@([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,7}$/i,
      error: "Not a valid e-mail address.",
    },
    phone: {
      reg: /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/,
      error: "Not a valid number.",
    },

    message: {
      reg: /^(?!\s*$).+/,
      error: "Message field cannot be empty.",
    },
  };

  var handleError = function(element, message) {
    element.addClass('input-error');
    var $err_msg = element.parent('div');
    $err_msg.find('.error').remove();
    var error = $('<div class="error"></div>').text(message);
    error.appendTo($err_msg);
    element.keyup(function() {
      $(error).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        element.removeClass('input-error');
      });
    });

  };

  this.validate = function() {
    var errorCount = 0;
    this.form.find("input, textarea").each(function(index, field) {
      var type = $(field).data("validation");
      var validation = Elements[type];
      if (validation) {
        if (!validation.reg.test($(field).val())) {
          errorCount++;
          handleError($(field), validation.error);
        }
      }
    })
    return errorCount == 0;
  };
};

$(function() {
  $("form#test").on("submit", function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    return new Validator(this).validate(); // "this" here refers to the form

  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font: 76% Verdana, sans-serif;
}

form {
  margin: 1em 0 0 2em;
  width: 90%;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input {
  font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
}

fieldset ul li input {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
}

form p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em 0 0 7em;
}

form p input {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.error {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 5.3em;
  color: red;
  padding-right: 1.3em;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.input-error {
  background: #ff9;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.success_msg {
  width: 350px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(213, 255, 187, 0.7);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="test">

  <fieldset>

    <legend>Contact information</legend>


    <div>
      <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" data-validation="name" />
    </div>


    <div>
      <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" data-validation="name" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" data-validation="email" />

    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="phone">phone</label>
      <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" data-validation="phone" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Gender:</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" data-validation="gender" />
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" data-validation="gender">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>select</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="demo1" data-validation="checkbox" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="demo2" data-validation="checkbox" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="demo3" ata-validation="checkbox" />
    </div>

    <select data-validation="selectOption">
      <option value="">Select any option</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <label>Upload:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" data-validation="file" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="message">Message:</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="15" data-validation="message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" /></p>

  </fieldset>
  <div class="success_msg">
    <p>Form submitted Successfully</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Please feel free to clear your doubts before you invest your time answering the question.

Comment: just change selector to  selector: $('#name'),

Comment: @BhumiShah I don't want to use Id's I want the form to validate all the text input fields all at once regardless of how many they are.

Comment: gone are the days to put js code for validation .. u can try this library itself - jquery form validator - http://www.formvalidator.net/ . Its simple and straight forward.

Comment: @NikolaLukic That is not a duplicate no two forms are same. I want my form to be validated by in different way.

Comment: Unless you're doing this just to learn how to do it yourself, I would recommend https://jqueryvalidation.org/. It's really simple to use and there's no reason to create more work for yourself on a project when others have solved this problem already.

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth Thanks, I want to make the form custom. I guess that could be done in a simple way but I got a bit of knowledge in that and no one has got time here. So, that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you were trying to achieve. This took longer than expected but I tried to achieve it. This whole form is custom form. You could have used the existing plugins to achieve it. Any which ways it took much time to figure it out. Consider the question as most of things are working, ignore if something's not what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* contact form validation */
  var Validator = function(formObject) {
    this.form = $(formObject);
    var Elements = {
      name: {
        reg: /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,20}$/,
        require: true,
        error: "Not a valid name.",
      },

      email: {
        reg: /^[a-z-0-9_+.-]+\@([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,7}$/i,
        error: "Not a valid e-mail address.",
      },
      phone: {
        reg: /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/,
        error: "Not a valid number.",
      },

      message: {
        reg: /^(?!\s*$).+/,
        error: "Message field cannot be empty.",
      },
      gender: {
        error: "gender is required",
      },
      selectOption: {
        error: "this field is required",
        required: true
      }
    };

    var handleError = function(element, message) {
      element.addClass('input-error');
      var $err_msg = element.parent('div');
      $err_msg.find('.error').remove();

      var error = $('<div class="error"></div>').text(message);
      error.appendTo($err_msg);
      console.log(element);


      element.on('keypress change', function() {
        $(error).fadeOut(1000, function() {
          console.log(element);
          element.removeClass('input-error');
        });
      });

    };

    /* Select Option */

    this.validate = function() {
      var errorCount = 0;

      this.form.find("select").each(function(index, field) {
        var type = $(field).data("validation");
        var validation = Elements[type];
        if ($(field).val() == "") {
          errorCount++;
          handleError($(field), validation.error);
        }
      });

      this.form.find("input, textarea").each(function(index, field) {
        var type = $(field).data("validation");
        var validation = Elements[type];
        if (validation !== undefined) {
          var re = new RegExp(validation.reg);
          if (validation) {
            if (!re.test($(field).val())) {
              errorCount++;
              handleError($(field), validation.error);
            }
          }
        }
      })

      /* Radio button */

      var radioList = $('input:radio');
      var radioNameList = new Array();
      var radioUniqueNameList = new Array();
      var notCompleted = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < radioList.length; i++) {
        radioNameList.push(radioList[i].name);
      }
      radioUniqueNameList = jQuery.unique(radioNameList);
      console.log(radioUniqueNameList);
      for (var i = 0; i < radioUniqueNameList.length; i++) {
        var field = $('#' + radioUniqueNameList[i]);
        var type = field.data("validation");
        var validation = Elements[type];
        if ($('input[name=' + type + ']:checked', '#test').val() == undefined) {
          errorCount++;
          handleError($(field), validation.error);
        }
      }

      return errorCount == 0;
    };
  };

  /* Submit form*/

  $(function() {

    $("form#test").on('submit', function(e) {
      var NoErrors = new Validator(this).validate();
      if (NoErrors == true) {
        $.ajax({
          url: this.action,
          type: this.method,
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function() {
            // AJAX request finished, handle the results and error msg
            $('.success_msg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
            $('input[type!="submit"], textarea').val('').removeClass('error');
          }
        });

      }
      return false;
    })

  })

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font: 76% Verdana, sans-serif;
}

form {
  margin: 1em 0 0 2em;
  width: 90%;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input {
  font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
}

fieldset ul li input {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font: 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
}

form p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em 0 0 7em;
}

form p input {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.error {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 5.3em;
  color: red;
  padding-right: 1.3em;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.input-error {
  background: #ff9;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.success_msg {
  width: 350px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(213, 255, 187, 0.7);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="test">
  <fieldset>

    <legend>Contact information</legend>


    <div>
      <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" data-validation="name" />
    </div>


    <div>
      <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" data-validation="name" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" data-validation="email" />

    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="phone">phone</label>
      <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" data-validation="phone" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <label>Gender:</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" data-validation="gender" />
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" data-validation="gender">
    </div>

    <select data-validation="selectOption">
      <option value="">Select any option</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <label for="message">Message:</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="15" data-validation="message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" /></p>

  </fieldset>
  <div class="success_msg">
    <p>Form submitted Successfully</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is the working code:

https://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/o2gxgz9r/47570/

I have changed selector to use id

You need to use loop in handle error:

```
var Validator = function(form) {

    this.form = $(form);

    var Elements = {
        name: {
            selector: $('input[type=text]'),
            reg: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,20}$/
        },

        email: {
            selector: $('input[type=email]'),
            reg: /^[a-z-0-9_+.-]+\@([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,7}$/i
        },

        message: {
            selector: $('textarea'),
            reg: /^\s+$/
        }
    };

    var handleError = function(element, message, v1) {
        if (v1.selector.length > 1) {
            var ss = v1.selector;

            $(ss).each(function(i, v) {
            $(v).removeClass('input-error');
            if($(v).val() == ''){
              $(v).addClass('input-error');
              var $err_msg = $(v).parent('div');
              if($(v).parent('div').find('.error').length == 0) {
                    var error = $('<div class="error"></div>').text(message);
               }else{
                    $(v).parent('div').find('.error').text('');
                    var error = $(v).parent('div').find('.error').text(message);
                    $(this).siblings('.error').show();
               }
               error.appendTo($err_msg);
             }else{
               $(v).siblings('.error').text('')
             }
             $(v).keyup(function() {
                 $(error).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                     element.removeClass('input-error');
                });
             });
          });
        } else {
            element.addClass('input-error');
            var $err_msg = element.parent('div');
            if(element.parent('div').find('.error').length == 0) {
                  var error = $('<div class="error"></div>').text(message);
             }else{
                  element.parent('div').find('.error').text('');
                  var error = element.parent('div').find('.error').text(message);
                  $(this).siblings('.error').show();
             }
            error.appendTo($err_msg);
            element.keyup(function() {
                $(error).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    element.removeClass('input-error');
                });
            });
        }

    };

    this.validate = function() {

        this.form.submit(function(e) {

            for (var i in Elements) {

                var type = i;
                var validation = Elements[i];
                switch (type) {
                    case 'name':
                        if (!validation.reg.test(validation.selector.val())) {
                            handleError(validation.selector, 'Not a valid name.', validation);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'email':
                        if (!validation.reg.test(validation.selector.val())) {
                            handleError(validation.selector, 'Not a valid e-mail address.', validation);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'message':
                        if (validation.reg.test(validation.selector.val()) || validation.selector.val() == '') {
                        handleError(validation.selector, 'Message field cannot be empty.', validation);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;


                }

            }

            e.preventDefault();
        });

    };
};

var validator = new Validator('#test');
validator.validate();
```

Comment: After enter and clear input, the jquery validation is not working

Comment: pl check now. Updated fiddle. Check only for name field

Comment: gone are the days to put js code for validation .. u can try this library itself - jquery form validator - http://www.formvalidator.net/ . Its simple and straight forward.

Comment: @Bhumi Shah. In this fiddle whenever we click send it's showing an error multiple times.

Comment: @Husna: I have updated fiddle and it's showing single time only